# Quartiles calculation in Postgresql Query

Tags: postgresql

I am having a hard time trying to get this done.  I have the following table:

```
cod_prod   seller   price    date
   A       Andres     10    anydate
   A       Paul       5     anydate
   A       Mike      2.5    anydate
   A       Josh      1.75   anydate
   A       Karen     7.5    anydate
 ....      .....     ...    .......
```

I am trying to calculate quartiles of the price for each product and classify each seller's price into 4 quartiles.

The output I am expecting is:

```
Cod_Prod   Seller  Price  Quartile  1stQ  2ndQ   3rdQ  4thQ
   A      Andres    10       4       2.5   5     7.5    10
   A      Karen    7.5       3       2.5   5     7.5    10
   A      Paul      5        2       2.5   5     7.5    10
   A      Mike     2.5       1       2.5   5     7.5    10
   A      Josh     1.75      1       2.5   5     7.5    10
  ..     .....      ....   ....     ....  ..     ...    ...
```

This table has thousands of distinct cod_prod and thousands of sellers.

I am trying this query:

```
with cte as ( 
            
            select seller, cod_prod, sum(price) as sum_price
            from tablename
            group by 2,1
```

)

```
select seller, 

      cod_prod, 
      sum_price,
      ntile(4) over (partition by seller order by sum_price asc) quartile
      from cte
```

But this not doing what I expect and still mising the `1stQ to 4thQ indicators bins`

I tried many different things but this is the closest I got from what I want.
Can someone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this query is exactly what you want, but I think can help you.

I calculated quartiles grouping by `cod_prod`.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT seller, cod_prod, sum(price) as sum_price
             FROM t
             GROUP BY seller, cod_prod),
             
     quartiles AS (SELECT 
                         cod_prod,
                         percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by sum_price asc) as "1stQ",
                         percentile_cont(0.50) within group (order by sum_price asc) as "2ndQ",
                         percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by sum_price asc) as "3rdQ",
                         percentile_cont(1) within group (order by sum_price asc) as "4thQ"
                   FROM cte
                   GROUP BY cod_prod)

SELECT cte.*,
       ntile(4) over (PARTITION BY cte.cod_prod ORDER BY sum_price ASC) quartile,
       quartiles.*
FROM cte
INNER JOIN quartiles ON cte.cod_prod = quartiles.cod_prod;
```

Comment: idk why, but won't let me use `within group ` says it should have a `'by` before ( i am using postgresql and querying datagrip through athena.

Comment: worked in my local postgresql but when I run online using athena(Presto  i guess) didn't work.  I read Presto'docs and there's nothin there a Within Group

Comment: I am not familiar with presto, but [this](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_percentile) may can help you. If you have only one price for each product-selller, so the `cte` subquery is unnecessary (I don't understand why you `sum` prices on `cte` subquery).

Comment: `percentile_cont()` Aggregate function is available from Postgresql 9.4